# The use of the verb "control" in the context

Tags: word-usage

Tell me please if the use of *control* sounds perfectly natural in the following sentence?

> Some parents tend to **control** their children too much.

What I mean by that is that some parents tend to control every aspect of their children. If it doesn't sound natural, what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: In your question "avery" should be "every"

Comment: I think the use of the word "control" here is natural and would be understood by a native English speaker (which includes me!).  I think it is likely to be understood how you intend as well - i.e. as a general statement that "some parents tend to control their childrens [behaviour, freedoms, etc] too much.  If you want to make it more explicit or add emphasis then you could say what you mean - for example "Some parents tend to control every aspect of their childrens lives" or "Some parents tend try to control their children too much in every aspect of their lives", something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what has been mentioned in the comments already, there's a nice example in [Overly-controlling parents cause their children lifelong psychological damage](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/overly-controlling-parents-cause-their-children-lifelong-psychological-damage-says-study-10485172.html) on how to say what you ask in your question:

> Parents who **exert too much control over their children** could be
>   causing them lifelong psychological damage

If you follow the same pattern, your sentence can be rephrased as:

> Some parents tend to exert too much control over their children.